# select from table where @variable in(table column)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, t-sql

could u please correct this sqlserver query :

```
select * from messages where @DepartID In(MsgTo)
```

@DepartID is a session variable that contains the Department ID.
MsgTo is a column in messages table that contains list of values , ex. : '12','10','13','25' .. etc

i used this code :

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from messages where @DepartID IN(MsgTo)"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartID ", session("DepartID")) ' = 12 for example

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
lbmsg.text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString ' returns 0 rows
```

sorry for my poor english

Comment: This is a case of _optimistic coding_. You are hoping that SQL Server will happen to notice that a column in your table looks like it might contain a list of values and, using its incredible Insight Engine, decode the list and intuit your intent. Not going to happen. You need to grab one of the common functions available on the Information Superhighway that separates a comma delimited list into a table of values, convert the strings to integers, and use that in your query.

Comment: u r right @HABO, i think they sould work arround it. I agree with function , i think it is the only one way ... thx

Answer (score 3):

I think you're just having some syntax trouble.  Have you declared the @DepartID variable in SQL?  You need to make a comparison to an existing column in your WHERE clause.  Like:

```
SELECT [ColumnName]
FROM [Table]
WHERE [ColumnName] = Value
```

If your department ID is a text-type column in SQL, you'll have to use single quotes on your input.  You can use single quotes anyways in integers like IDs when you query them with an "IN" statement and it will work anyways.  Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [messages]
WHERE [MsgTo] = @DepartID
```

So if you replace your @DepartID variable out with your value and then execute the statement, it will return all information for each row where your [MsgTo] column equals your @DepartID.

If you are passing multiple @DepartIDs, then you would have to pass a comma-delimited text list to the "IN" clause with your variable like the example below:

```
SELECT *
FROM [messages]
WHERE [MsgTo] IN ('1','5','3','12','30')

--Example where @DepartID = '1','5','3','12','30'
```

I'm not sure what language you're using to execute the SQL, but if this doesn't work, try encapsulating your SQL statement within an EXEC() like below:

```
EXEC(
    SELECT *
    FROM [messages]
    WHERE [MsgTo] = @DepartID
)
```

If your MsgTo column contains a string list of values and you want to search through it for a single @DepartID, then use this code:

```
DECLARE @DepartID as INT; SET @DepartID = 12; --Hard coded example

SELECT *
FROM [messages]
WHERE [MsgTo] LIKE ('%,'''+@DepartID+''',%')
```

Comment: thx EMUEVIL .. actually what i want is to check if the departID in MsgTo column as list of values, for example: if i sent a message to multi departments and stored the department ID's in MsgTo column as : '12','13','15,'20' etc.. then i want to get all messages that sent to department 12. using like clause will return 12 and 122 and 121etc..

Comment: @Eid Try my last example.  It will select all rows that were sent to the departID specified:

`DECLARE @DepartID AS INT; SET @DepartID = 12;

SELECT *
FROM [messages]
WHERE [MsgTo] LIKE ('%,''+@DepartID+'',%')`

Comment: Using Like clause is not a good method in this setuation, it may return values like 12 . ex: 112,1112,1211,1232 etc , just try it

Comment: If you include the comma delimiter as part of the regex, it shouldn't pull up the wrong values.